# Sharepoint List Calculation #Div/0!

Tags: list, column

I have a Sharepoint list which contains a field which is calculated based on two other columns. However when the two other columns both contain zeroes the result comes out as #DIV/0!.

The actual formula is very simple it is: [columnA]/[ColumnB]

Both columns are formatted as numbers, I have tried this a few times and it comes out the same each time

Comment: What do you expect? Division by zero is mathematically undefined. Most programming languages and calculations either return a "division by zero" error of some sort or "undefined." You could do something like =IF([ColumnB]=0,"My own error message",[ColumnA]/[ColumnB])

Answer (score 2):

You can not divide by zero.

Use this to check if the denominator is equal to zero.

```
=IF([ColumnB]=0,"Division By Zero!",[ColumnA]/[ColumnB])
```

[Why can't we divide by zero?](http://www.math.utah.edu/~pa/math/0by0.html)
[How different programming languages handle division by 0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2388842/how-different-programming-languages-handle-division-by-0)

Comment: In case ColumnB is empty or string value it is better to use:
IF(ISERROR([ColumnA]/[ColumnB]),"Div by zero",[ColumnA]/[ColumnB])